# display custom portfolio tags

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, shortcode, tags, front-end

This is a part from the code that is used to display portfolio categories:

```
$post_cat = array();
                    $post_cat = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, "portfolio_category");
                    $post_cats = array();

         $attachments = get_post_meta($post->ID, '300-160-image', true);

        if ($attachments) {         
                        $post_cat = array();
                        $post_cat = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, "portfolio_category");
                        $post_cats = array();

                        $cats_pf_this = implode(":", $post_cats);

        $fg_imagemain.='{"url": "'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/image.php?'.str_replace("&amp;", "&", $image_resizer_output).'image='.$attachments.'", "aid": '.$post->ID.', "color": "'.addslashes(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumbnail_hover_color', true)).'", "thumb_title": "'.addslashes($thumb_title).'", "thumb_descr": "'.addslashes($thumb_descr).'", "thumb_cats": "'.addslashes($cats_pf_this).'", "fullimgsrc": "}';

        var fg_divhoverbgmetadata = $("<div>").addClass("hoverbgpfthnailmetadata").html('<span class="thumb_title">'+srcobj.thumb_title+'</span><span class="thumb_cats">'+srcobj.thumb_cats+'</span><span class="thumb_plus">+</span>');
```

What I want to do, is, to display also the portfolio tags.
I think the first step is to duplicate this:

```
$post_cats = array();
                    $post_cat = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, "portfolio_category");
```

like :

```
$post_tags = array();
                    $post_cat = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, "portfolio_tags");
```

and the same for rest of the code.
I've tried this but with no success, I can't make it work  to display portfolio items tags.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nobody? My question is not relevant?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to know the name for your "portfolio_tags" taxonomy.  Check where it is defined as a custom taxonomy, and it will need to be added to the portfolio custom post type.

The [register_taxonomy()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) function would be your theme like this:

```
register_taxonomy('portfolio_tags',
   array('portfolio'), 
   array('hierarchical' => false, 'show_ui' => true, 'query_var' => true, 
   'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio-tags' )));
```

Or you could be using a custom post / custom taxonomy plugin -- then you would need to check what id was given (for example, it could be "portfolio_tag" instead)

Once you have confirmed this, you should use [get_the_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) instead, since it is part of the Wordpress API ([wp_get_object_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms) isn't using the object cache so it would be less efficient)

```
 $post_cat = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'portfolio_tags' );
```

Finally, in order to use `$post-ID`, make sure you are in The Loop or you have referenced the `global $post` object.